# What is a flexitarian?

Tags: philosophy, terminology

I've heard the term used now and then in various contexts. What exactly is a flexitarian, and should it be classed as a dietary requirement?

To my understanding, it really just means a person is aiming to eat a lower quantity of meat, which isn't really a dietary requirement as they aren't removing anything, just changing their ratio of intakes.

Comment: IMO a flexitarian is just an omnivore who will not insist on eating meat three times a day and who will not complain if a meal is vegetarian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the Flexitarian Diet is a semi-vegetarian style of eating that encourages eating less meat and more plant-based foods.
But there are no specific rules or suggestions other than that.